# How can I prove that affine hypersurface $V(X^2 + Y^5+Z^5 + 1) \subset \mathbb{A}^3$ is not rational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, singularity-theory, projective-varieties

$(*)$ I would like to prove that  $Spec(\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]/\langle X^2+Y^5+Z^5+1  \rangle)$ is not rational (or equivalently that $Proj (\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z,T]/\langle X^2 T^3+Y^5+Z^5+T^5  \rangle)$ is not rational).

$(**)$ More generally, I am interested in proving that the hypersurfaces defined by $X^2 + Y^c+Z^c + 1$ where $c \geq 5$ is odd are not rational.

The first thing I tried to do was to consider the projective completion $V(X^2 T^3 + Y^5+Z^5 + T^5) \subset \mathbb{P}^3$. This projective hypersurface has an isolated singular point at $(1:0:0:0)$ and is normal. Magma calculates that this singular projective hypersurface is birational to a smooth projective surface with non-zero geometric genus. This shows (by birational equivalence) that $X^2 + Y^5+Z^5 + 1$ is not rational. The same idea works in the general case. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to calculate the geometric genus by hand, so I haven't been able to prove what I suspect to be true.

Any method of proving $(*)$ or $(**)$ would be useful.

**Remark**: $Spec(\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]/\langle X^2+Y^3+Z^3+1  \rangle)$ is rational.

Comment: Sorry, which part are you unable to prove? In general, you probably want to look at the canonical bundle of your surface (or rather its projective completion).

Comment: @TabesBridges I would like to prove that $Spec(\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]/\langle X^2+Y^5+Z^5+1  \rangle$ or equivalently, that $Proj (\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z,T]/\langle X^2 T^3+Y^5+Z^5+T^5  \rangle)$ is not rational. (I will edit my question to clarify this.)

If I let $X = Proj(\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z,T]/\langle X^2 T^3+Y^5+Z^5+T^5  \rangle)$, and let $K_X$ be a canonical divisor, I suppose that since $X$ and $\mathbb{P}^3$ are normal and $X$ is a Cartier divisor of $\mathbb{P^3}$, I can use adjunction to say that $K_X = (X + K_{\mathbb{P^3}})|_X$. 

But how does this tell me whether or not $X$ is rational?

Comment: OK, it's a matter of not knowing how to calculate $p_g$ by hand. Well in this case, since $X$ is cut out by a section of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(5)$ and $K_{\mathbb P^3} \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(-4)$, we get $K_X \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(1)$. Since $X$ is normal, I believe you can now just say $p_g(X) = h^0(K_X) = 4$. To be sure, you can blow up the singularity, determine its effect on the canonical bundle, and then compute global sections.

Comment: @TabesBridges This partially helps. I'd guess you mean that $\mathcal{O}_X(K_X) \sim i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1)$ where $i : X \to \mathbb{P}^3$ is the implicit closed immersion.

Comment: At this point I'm confused. To show that $X$ is not rational, it would suffice to show that $p_g(\tilde{X}) = h^2(\tilde X,\mathcal{O}_{\tilde X}) \neq 0$ where $\tilde X$ is a resolution of singularities of $X$. But the relationship between   $h^2(\tilde X,\mathcal{O}_{\tilde X})$ and  $h^2(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$ isn't clear because the singular point need not be rational. 

I'd guess my problem with this computation is that I don't know how to do any of the following: "To be sure, you can blow up the singularity, determine its effect on the canonical bundle, and then compute global sections."

Comment: That's precisely what I mean; I meant to write $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3(1)}|_X$ which is the same thing. The geometric genus on a smooth variety is either $h^2(\mathcal O_X)$ or $h^0(K_X)$; they are equal by Serre Duality. The reason I didn't pass to a full resolution at first is because one should be able to compute the geometric genus just on the normalization, which is the given projective model.

Comment: Basic example: blow up the origin $p:X\to\mathbb A^2$ with coordinates $(x,y)$, so we have new coordinates $(x,xy)$ on one chart. The generator of $K_{\mathbb A^2}$, $dx \wedge dy$, therefore pulls back to $dx\wedge d(xy) = dx\wedge (ydx - xdy) = -x(dx\wedge dy)$. Now since $x=0$ cuts out the exceptional divisor $E$, this tells us that $p^* K_{\mathbb A^2} \cong K_X\otimes \mathcal O(-E)$, i.e. $K_X \cong p^*(K_{\mathbb A^2})\otimes \mathcal O(E)$. A similar local calculation should tell you the canonical of the resolution in terms of the canonical downstairs and the exceptional divisor.

Comment: Thanks @TabesBridges. I will think about this technique and see if it gets me somewhere. I'm no expert, but I suspect the calculations might get pretty hairy, pretty fast.